How do I show that the region {r > 2m} of the Schwarzschild spacetime is globally hyperbolic?
How do I show that the region {r > 2m} of the Schwarzschild spacetime is globally hyperbolic?  I am just starting with this so I don't really know how to lay out this arguments. I consulted Beem's global Lorentzian geometry https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&opi=89978449&url=https://www.math.auckland.ac.nz/~hekmati/Books/GLG.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwjXreWvr8SFAxXo9LsIHZiRAQ4QFnoECBYQAQ&usg=AOvVaw2fp3z_iYYlPIYvhWI-tp0z
but I could 't find anything
I think it is better to use a characterization of global hyperbolicity  to verify this. The one I know is that global hyperbolicity is equivalent to the existence of a Cauchy surface. But then how do I prove this?
The Schwarzschild metric is,
$$\mathrm{d}s^2 = \left( 1-\frac{2M}{r}\right)\mathrm{d}\tau^2 + \left( 1-\frac{2M}{r}\right)^{-1} \mathrm{d}r^2 + r^2 \mathrm{d}\theta^2 + r^2 \sin^2 \theta \, \mathrm{d}\phi^2$$

Some relevant definitions
Global hyperbolicity: $(M, g)$ Lorentzian is globally hyperbolic if it is  causal and all $J^+(p) \cap J^+(q)$ are compact where $J^+(p)$ is the causal future of $p \in M$
Proposition: Characterization of global hyperbolicity: $(M, g)$ is globally hyperbolic iff there exists a Cauchy surface $S$ in $M$
Def of Cauchy surface:  A closed causal set is a Cauchy surface if $D(S) =M$. Otherwise the future Cauchy horizon of S is $H^+(S) :=\overline{D^+(S)} \setminus I ^-(D^+) $
$I^-(p) $ denotes chronological past of p
$D(S) =D(S^+) \cup D(S^-) $
$D(S^+) =\{p\in M|$ every past inextendible curve starting at p intersects $S \} $
$D(S^-) =\{p\in M|$ every future inextendible curve starting at p intersects $S \} $
$\gamma(t)$ is past-inextendible if that the limit $\lim_{t \to a^+}\gamma(t)$ does not exist
$\gamma(t)$ is future-inextendible means that the limit $\lim_{t \to b^-}\gamma(t) $ does not exist
Edit:

I will try to see if $S={(t,x,y,z)\in M: t=0}$ is a Cauchy surface. I have to prove that $D(S)= M$, with S causal, which means that for any two points of S there is no causal curve between them. It is obvious that $D(S) \subseteq M $. I just have to prove that $M \subseteq D(S)$. Take p $\in M$ nad at arbitrary $\gamma \in D(S)$, $\gamma:I=(a,b)\to M$, causal that is either past-inextendible or future-inextendible starting at $p$ ( i.e. $\gamma(0)=p$). I have to show that $\gamma$ intersects S.   I am stuck at this point how should I continue?

You might want to provide the definitions of global hyperbolicity and a Cauchy surface. And show what you have tried so far. Have you tried verifying the definition directly?

@Deane  I was adviced to use a characterization. The definition is not very friendly. The Cauchy surface one is the most well known but I don't know how to construct such a surface On another hand, I added some definitions. I believed people familiar with the subject should  know them because each definitions depends on more and more definitions where am I supposed to stop?

The metric is spherically symmetric. So it's reasonable to look for a spherical Cauchy surface.

@Deane Yeah but how does one even look for one? All I have is the definitions and no concrete examples

Write down a concrete example and try it.

@Deane See my edit, how should I continue?
